# Count of range of columns with null rows in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have run into a weird problem. It may be simple one, but I am unable to trace out a solution for the same.

I have 10 columns in excel where 8 columns has data and 2 columns doesn't have the data, Now want to get the count of the null columns.

```
a   b   c   d   e(null count)
10      10        2
5                 3
                  4
```

I tried using `ISBlank`, `CountBlank` but nothing is woking for me.

### Edit

When I use count bank I am getting some weird symbol equal to zero (sorry, I am unable to attach screen shot).

My code is

```
COUNTBLANK(D9:I9)=0
```

### Edit

This is my code:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTBLANK(D9:I9)=0,COUNTBLANK(K9:P9)=0,Q9="",R9="",T9="",COUNTBLANK(V9:AF9)=0,AH9="",AK9="",AM9="",AO9=""),"",SUM(D9:I9,K9:P9,Q9,R9,T9,V9:AF9,AH9,AK9,AM9,AO9))
```

personal data:

```
<header id="head">
<!-- <img src='Images/12.jpg' width=screen.width >  -->
this is god
</header>
<script>
/* <!--function slide(){  */
var ima = ['12.jpg','Pooja Vidhanam Pic.jpg' ];
/* document.getElementById("head").innerHTML ="'"+"Images/"+ima[1]+"'";
var txt="'"+"Images/"+ima[0]+"'"; */
for (i = 0; i < ima.length; i++) {
var x = document.createElement("IMG");
x.setAttribute("src", "Images/"+ima[i]);
 x.setAttribute("width", "304");
x.setAttribute("height", "228");
x.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock"); 
//x.setAttribute(name, value)
//document.getElementById("head").appendChild(document.createElement("<img src= txt width=screen.width >"));
document.getElementById("head").appendChild(x);
//sleep(1000);
}
/* for (i=0;i<ima.length;i++){
    <img src="Images/"+images[i]+" width=screen.width" >

    document.getElementById("head").innerHTML=ima[i];

} */

</script>

<!-- <script>
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
 document.getElementById("head").innerHTML = cars[0];
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    text += cars[i] + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("head").innerHTML = text;
}

</script> -->
```

Comment: Well, COUNTBLANK(range) ought to work, this is exactly what it was designed for. Your problem probably lies elsewhere, maybe you can provide more relevant details?

Comment: `COUNTBLANK` should work fine, what does it return? Are you sure blank cells are really blank?

Comment: @Ctx Thanks for your reply....all columns are blank I have double checked..

Comment: @BrakNicku thanks for your reply... all cells in columns are blank

Comment: _When I use count bank I am getting some wierd symbol equal to zero_ sorry, it's not clear what you mean. Your code should be `=COUNTBLANK(D9:I9)`, if you still do not get correct results, you should check `LEN` and `CODE` function results for blank cells.

Comment: Is the `=0` a typo? The formula that you wrote would return TRUE or FALSE depending on whether there were 0 or more blanks in that row

Comment: @SamGilbert Thanks for your reply... yes there is a `if` condition and I am using this for comparision..... I am checking blanks but instead of returning any numeric value function returing some special symbol... not sure why... can you please help me if there is any alternative available

Comment: @BrakNicku apologize for not giving full infor...I am uisng that in a if statement hence my formula will start as `==if` and rest continues..`if(AND(CountBlank(A1:D1)=0,CountBlank(f1:k1)=0))`.. This way my formula goes.

Comment: It would help if you could supply the whole formula? Also, what is the symbol that is returned? as per the other replies this formula should work so there must be something else going on. (alternative could be `=COUNTIF(D9:I9, "")`)

Comment: @SamGilbert.. please check my second edit for the full formula... thanks for your suggestion will try `countif`

Comment: This formula works for me. I would suggest to break it up and test the individual parts to narrow down the issue

Comment: Probably there's a problem with your `AND` formula logic. If you describe what it's supposed to return in different cases we could help you fix it.

Comment: @SamGilbert... thanks for your reply... but `CountIF` worked.. thanksyo you can answer the question with `countif` will accept as asnwer

Comment: @BrakNicku.. Thanks for your reply but countIF worked.. thanks

Comment: There could then be something present in these cells (perhaps other formulas?). For example a cell with formula `=""` isn't a blank cell

Comment: @SamGilbert - Yes, a cell with `""` is not truly blank but the [COUNTBLANK function](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/countblank-function-c72134a2-695e-43ab-a3f3-714aa770f385) counts it as blank.